# Is it possible to execute arbitrary javascript in IE Devtools?

Tags: ie11-developer-tools

Trying to troubleshoot something that of course only happens in IE, but I can't seem to get it to allow me to execute any code in the JS console.  Is there some magic keypress that turns that function on?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a single line of code, hitting [Enter] should execute the command.

If you paste in multiple lines of code, your editor will get set to Multi-line mode. In order to execute script you will then have to press [Ctrl]+[Enter]

You could also always click the green arrow to the right of the text field to execute the script.